# Scala File poller design

Tags: scala, akka

I need a help on creating a scala service that polls a file creation and then process a function created in scala. Let me give you a brief background of what i am doing.

I am scraping a few financial websites for data using python based tool called scrappy and creating a storing as a csv file on my linux system. It also creates a complete file in a directory when csv creation is complete. That scrappy churns out 47 csv files through out the day and thus 45 complete file.

I have learned ( although very new to it) scala and wrote the csv parser and mongo db loader in scala. It works fine if it runs it individually but i need a mechanism in scala which is

1. Like a service .i.e. process should start at a time of the day and stop at certain time of the day.
2. During that service alive period it should look at the complete folder and run each file in a multi thread fashion.

For example in complete directory it will write 2 files  NASDAQ_20141114.com and NYSE_20141114.com. The service should start 2 child for NASDAQ and NYSE.

I have tried looking at akka but it appears complicated to me.

Please help and suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 provides the [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) API ([example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html))

This can be used from Scala :

```
val watchService = FileSystems.getDefault.newWatchService()
Paths.get("/foo/bar").register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE)

while(true) {
    val key = watchService.take()
    key.pollEvents() foreach { event =>
        event.kind() match {
            case ENTRY_CREATE =>    //...
            case ENTRY_DELETE =>    //...
            case x =>
                logger.warn(s"Unknown event $x")
        }
    }
    key.reset()
}
```

Example from [WatchService combined with Akka actors](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/watchservice-combined-with-akka-actors.html)

You can also use avaliable wrapper libraries such as [schwatcher](https://github.com/lloydmeta/schwatcher)

Additionaly you can use Apache Camels [File component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) and Camel [plugs in nicely to Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html) and [Quartz](http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html)

There are also custom built filetransfer solutions such as [JADE - JobScheduler Advanced Data Exchange](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=295&page=jade_overview_en.html) that can trigger your program when a file is avaliable. (includes a scheduler)

For scheduler I would suggest [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) or [Jobscheduler](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=62&page=osource_scheduler_introduction_en.htm)